# Alias with arguments in ZSH shell

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

I want to open a directory in VSCode easily. Currently, I have to either go to VSCode and add the wanted directory to my workspace, or I have to go to the ZSH shell and type:

```
open '/Users/myUser/Documents/Project' -a 'visual studio code'
```

That's a bit hard and long to type. Is there anyway to have an alias which kind of takes in arguments? Like the above command should be replaced by the following:

```
code '/Users/myUser/Documents/Project'
```

or if that isn't possible:

```
code -path='/Users/myUser/Documents/Project'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a **function** or a **script** for this purpose, because arguments are always appended afterwards, i.e. after the alias has been expanded. See the section _ALIASES_ in the _zshall_ man page. Aliases are not intended to be used for the task you want to do. If you want a handy abbreviation of the script for your interactive use, first create a script (function) with a name fitting the conventions of your project, and then create an alias for this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias is just alias, it doesn't support argument. If you need to do argument parsing, function is what you need.

Some good tutorials for cmd parsing

- [How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

**Solution to open vscode in command line**

- Open "Command Palette" with Cmd + Shift + P
- Type and search with "install code", choose the item
- Open a new shell, try `code --help`